# Time series data and UTC conversion

Tags: database, time-series

I'm storing data in minute, hour, day, month and year buckets. All data is stored in UTC. Let's assume a client is in PDT time (-07:00 UTC)

If the client wants to query for the hour sum of `4/23/2016 7:00pm` in their timezone they would convert the time to UTC - `4/24/2016 2:00am` and make the query. Image for reference.

[image: Hour conversion from PDT to UTC]

This works perfectly fine for hour and minute buckets. However, let's look at the case where the client wants the sum for a day bucket. If the client wants the local day dum for `4/24/2016` they would convert the time to UTC which resolves in `4/24/2016` also. The `4/24/2016` UTC day bucket contains data for 7 hours from the local day `4/23/2016` and misses the last 7 hours of the local day `4/24/2016`. This seems like a problem since the query will not return the correct sum. It returns the sum for the UTC day.

Am I missing something with this example? Or is storing data buckets in time intervals > hour a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your day, month, and year buckets all have a timezone baked into them (UTC0 in this case). If you want to report day/month/year aggregates for a different timezeone, that's ultimately a different collection of hours, and you'll need to compute and store them using that timezone's notion of a day's beginning and end.

Comment: This is what I'm thinking. Is there a common design pattern for this?

Comment: Not really, beyond noting that if timezones are to be accommodated, the TZ offset becomes a formal query parameter. Whether you choose to pre-compute day/month/year aggregations for certain timezones or do that on the fly for any timezone is going to depend on your resources and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Since the user's perspective in this example is PST and the data is stored in UTC, you must have a flag or indication somehow that the desire is to see an entire day's worth of aggregates.  If I am PST, regardless of what time it is on 4/24, if I select to return an entire day's worth of aggregate, I would want to query the UTC from 3/24 7:00 am to 3/25 7:00 pm.  If this is your intention, it becomes a modified start and end date based on the fact the user selected to sum up a Day's worth of data.  I don't see any issue with your design of storing data in minutes, hours, days, months.

It is really a question of your definition of a day's worth of data.   Is that 24 hours prior to the time specified or just 24 hours of that day which I discussed above.

Comment: My intention is just 24 hours of the day. But if I'm storing day buckets and looking at day buckets I wont be able to query from 3/24 7:00am to 3/24 7:00pm if the day bucket just has the aggregate data for the day, since that would require going down to the hour level.